# AngularJs dropdown menu-content covering menu button

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-material

My dropdown menu content is covering up my dropdown button, any idea how to fix it? I want it to appear directly underneath my dropdown button. I have tried creating a class and style it in CSS as "position: absolute;" but it doesn't work. 
Here is my code in angular:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrll" ng-app="Fruit">

  <div>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Fruits
      </md-button>
      <md-menu-content class="dropdown" >

         <md-menu-item >
                        <md-button ng-click="apple()">Apple</md-button>
                        </md-menu-item>
                        <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button ng-click="blueberry()">Blueberry </md-button>
                        </md-menu-item>
       </md-menu>
      </md-menu-content>    
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my Angular app

```
angular
  .module('Fruit',['ngMaterial'])


  .controller('Ctrll', function () {
    var originatorEv;

    this.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
      originatorEv = ev;
      $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };
});
```

I have added it to codepen. Here is how my code looks like in action. http://codepen.io/zcook/pen/YqramL

Also, does anyone know how to change the color of the background of the dropdown menu content?

Comment: Could you post a snippet or a jsFiddle link to demonstrate what is happening? This code doesn't appear to provide enough evidence of the cause.

Comment: it looks like something in the link. I want the menu content to appear under the icon. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu   
EDIT: I have added it to codepen. Here is how my code looks like in action. http://codepen.io/zcook/pen/YqramL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why can't you change the CSS property of class .md-open-menu-container.md-active?

```
.md-open-menu-container.md-active{
  top: 45px !important;
}
```

Check this updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/sesubash/pen/RaLyoq)

Comment: You might want to refer this 
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-behavior

Positioning the menu below the emitting element separates it from its context.

and depending on your requirement you might want to use a drop-down button

http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-dropdown-buttons